# AngularJS can't find $locationProvider module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting the following error when I try to use $locationProvider. Do I need to import the module somehow?

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $locationProviderProvider <- $locationProvider
```

This is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'duScroll', 'duParallax', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngRoute'
    ]);

myApp.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the code you posted works by [itself](http://plnkr.co/edit/OmGQiU6vPgrDjMr6SxFM?p=preview):

Given your error message, I think you tried to inject $locationProvider in a different function, so it tries to find `$locationProviderProvider`.

Look for a callback function that is not passed to `config` that injects `$locationProvider`. You'll want to inject `$location` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I've checked my controllers and I had a line still there using $locationProvider...